# Javascript Sort Function Error: 'The right-hand side of an arithmetic operation must be of type 'any', 'number', 'bigint' or an enum type'

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

TS is giving me an error in my Angular 7 project for the sort function below. The error message is: "The right-hand side of an arithmetic operation must be of type 'any', 'number', 'bigint' or an enum type'".

Technically this will work if I comment the function out and then the application run. Once the application is running I can uncomment the function and everything works as expected including the sort function.

Basically I am trying to sort dates on descending order.

```
    this.SortArray = this.project.Attributes.sort(function (a, b) {

        return new Date(a.EffDate) - new Date(b.EffDate);
      });
```

Comment: Since this is TS code it is difficult to answer this without a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) version of your code using an online code editor like codesandbox.io, etc.

Comment: `(new Date(a.EffDate)).valueOf() - (new Date(b.EffDate)).valueOf()` Note that a) `EffDate` should be in ISO 8601 format to work cross-browser and b) sorting alphabetically on ISO 8601 dates works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the following in your sort function:

```
return new Date(a.EffDate).getTime() - new Date(b.EffDate).getTime();
```

TypeScript definitions prevent dates to be compared directly, so you have to convert them into numbers first.